# How do I use custom hibernate SQL under Spring/Hibernate Transaction Management

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have the following Spring/Hibernate configs:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jndiDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            ...
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" 
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

I am extensively using spring transaction annotations to control transaction propagation methods throughout my code base.  It is all working great.

I have a need to perform an update that will affect many rows at once and I want to blend it in with the rest of my transaction logic.  The last thing I want to do is to bull in a china shop and load all objects into memory and loop through them changing them one at a time.

I am trying something like:

```
            @Autowired
            private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
            ...
            String hql = "UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_LIST WHERE ID IN :list";
            // I see the transaction and get an error when I try to start a new one.
            Transaction trans = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction();
            Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql);
            query.setParameterList("list", listOfIds);
            success = (query.executeUpdate() == listOfIds.size());
```

I have tried dropping this into a method with its own transaction instructions, but am not seeing any evidence that it is being executed (other than a lack of errors).

What is the recommended way to include custom Hibernate SQL into Spring managed transactions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. What happens when you fix the SQL query (yours is invalid) and execute it inside a `@Transactional` method? Why do you think you need to do anything special to have that specific query executed as part of the current transaction?

Comment: The SQL above is invalid.  I changed it here so it didn't distract from the question.  The reason I think I need to do something special is because I need a reference to the "Current Session" in order to create a Query object.  My gut feel is that this bypasses Spring's transaction management.  When I try executing the above code inside of an active transaction, I get no errors and no updates to the table.